# Get entity by its parent entity's value in Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

Imagine we have this simple entity in ES

```
user {
 username: "ultrauser"
 name: "Greg"
 address: [
  { city: "London" }, {city: "Prague" }
 ]
}
```

I need a query, which will return me all addreses for user "ultrauser".

I'm using NEST and for now, I'm doing it the way I select user where username="ultrauser" and then read only the addresses field by myself. So the ES will return me whole user entity, which contain addresses too.

But is it possible for ES to make query like "Give me all addresses, which belongs to user 'ultrauser'"?

I need ES to return list of addresses entities, not user entity, containing addresses. It is simple when you go from root to leafs (get user.address.city), but how can I select from leafs to root easily?

**Important is, we can not use parent-child or nested document features because of other reasons.**

Thanks for all you ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably read this article: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch/ You're trying to apply RDBMS concepts to elasticsearch and that is usually a bad idea. Really, even if you are storing objects, they are still stored flat in elasticsearch behind the scenes.

I think this query will get you to where you want to be though, if I'm understanding you correctly:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "username": "some matched item"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "filtered": {
                        "filter": {
                            "exists": { "field" : "address" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "fields": [
        "address"
    ]
}
```

Does it matter if you extract the addresses or if you ask elasticsearch to do it for you? Sometimes you don't want to send all that data over the wire if not needed and that might be your reason.

This will still return something like this:

```
hits: [
{
_index: indexname
_type: typename
_id: id
_score: 1.4142135
fields: {
address: [
{someaddress_object}
]
}
}, ...
```

So you will still need to loop through the results anyway when you get them back, just the result size is smaller.

Comment: Yes, I need it to be smaller. I created this simple sample, because user containt a lot more fields and it is does not make sense to get the whole user, when I need only one field. I will try your suggestion and let you know (and mark the answer). But it maybe takes some time, because I'm using generic NEST, so I have to rewrite the query. Thank you

Comment: Just one question - why should I use Filters then? If I want one specific address, which belongs to user "ultrauser", then I can easily make the query for the user, set the filter on field "address" and then say I want only field "address" returned. But it will contain all user's addresses and I have to apply the filter once more (with linq or something). I will only know, that the desired address is somewhere in the result.

Comment: @MartinPotvrzenejBrabec You don't really. I was just showing a slightly more complicated example, if you were looking for multiple users you would want to filter out those that didn't have addresses. Or let's say you were querying on some other value (like show me all the addresses in some city or whatever). The important bit of this answer is the "fields" stanza at the end